# Can I make a TextInput required?

Tags: validation, actionscript-3, apache-flex, textinput

I have a lot of code like

```
if (myTextInput.text != "") {
    handleEvent();
}
```

Does TextInput have some property I can use to automatically check for an empty string?
 Similar to how if I set it like :

```
<s:TextInput id="myInput" enter="myInputHandler()" restrict="A-Za-Z0-9"/>
```

then `myInputHandler()` only gets called if the text is alphanumeric. I'd like to add an additional restriction that length is greater than 0.

I know about the validators, but I still have to call them manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make a `TextInput` component "required", you can, for example, create your own text input component and use a property to indicate if the control is required or not, and some event listeners like for `FocusEvent.FOCUS_OUT` event to force your user to enter something in that input.

For that, take this example :

```
package myComponent
{
    import flash.events.FocusEvent;     
    import spark.components.TextInput;

    public dynamic class MyTextInput extends TextInput
    {
        private var _required:Boolean = false;
        public function MyTextInput()
        {
            super();
            this.addEventListener(FocusEvent.FOCUS_OUT, on_KeyDown);
        }
        public function set required(required:Boolean): void {
            this._required = required;
        }
        public function get required(): Boolean {
            return this._required;
        }       
        private function on_KeyDown(e:FocusEvent): void {           
            if(this.text == '' && this._required){
                this.setFocus();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Of course this is just an example, you can use any behavior you want when your user left the input empty ...

Then to use that new component :

```
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
               <!-- don't forget to include the namespace definition for your custom component -->
               xmlns:MyComponent="myComponent.*">

    <MyComponent:MyTextInput required="true" restrict="A-Za-z0-9"/>

</s:Application>
```

For more about creating your own components, take a look [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf68268-7ffb.html).

Hope that can help.

Comment: I am going to hold off on accepting this for another day, in case there's something simple we're both overlooking, but yes this addresses my issue and is the sort of thing I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
if ( String(myTextInput.text).length > 0 ) 
{ 
    handleEvent(); 
}
```

If that's all the code you need (no extra commands) then just do as one-line :

```
if ( String(myTextInput.text).length > 0 ) { handleEvent(); }
```

Comment: I think that OP's problem is to avoid repeating that code not the code itself ;-)

Comment: Hi @akmozo, why do you think that? I looked at _"Does TextInput have some property I can use to automatically check for an empty string?"_... They are checking by `IS NOT ""` so I recommend code for `IF length BIGGER THAN 0` check. This is based on _"I'd like to add an additional restriction that length is greater than 0"_. They never said nothing about not-repeating. My understanding is deep down they prefer to check by **String length** instead of by **String contents**.

Comment: Hi, I think that OP is looking for some attribute like the HTML5's `required` one to force user to enter text (or at least check if the input is not empty without writing the same checking code every time : `txt.text != ''` or `txt.length == 0` ...) ...

Comment: @Akmozo please edit their question to get that point across. You've made more sense than Asker did (esp: HTML5's `required` example). They didn't even mention components or tag Flex.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, this is not the kind of solution but, you can put the TextField into a FormItem, which has the "required" field